# Linux: Python can't download pip

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I'm running Ubuntu focal fossa 20.04, and I just tried installing python. It worked, however, I can't use pip. I tried looking up answers but that didn't fix it. Here is the problem.

**Terminal**

Input

```
user@hostname:~$ python3 get-pip.py
```

Output

```
python3: can't open file '/home/user/get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

**(Edit)Followed first answer;**

Input

```
user@hostname:~/Downloads$ python3 get-pip.py
```

Output

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 520, in _get_decompress_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 568, in _get_data
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 523, in _get_decompress_func
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Downloads/get-pip.py", line 24184, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/Downloads/get-pip.py", line 139, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/get-pip.py", line 115, in bootstrap
    monkeypatch_for_cert(tmpdir)
  File "/home/user/Downloads/get-pip.py", line 96, in monkeypatch_for_cert
    from pip._internal.commands.install import InstallCommand
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 241, in load_module
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 709, in _get_module_code
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 570, in _get_data
   zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

**Update, installed zlib, had to download a different get-pip.py, and it worked!**

Comment: As you're using ubuntu, you can install pip via apt `apt install python3-pip`

Comment: How did you install python?  Via a package manager or by compiling it from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen get-pip.py, but after a quick research, it looks like this is a manual way of installing pip.

However you need to actually download the script. It's not something that's bundled with Python.

> To manually install pip, securely 1 download get-pip.py by following this link: get-pip.py. Alternatively, use curl: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

Please review: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/